# What library should i use to download a copy of Gmail emails through Python script?

Tags: python, gmail-imap

In a python script, i want to be able to connect to the gmail server, and then download all my emails into a single .mbox file. Is this possible? If so, what library is used and where can i get it from? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) from Python standard library.

```
import imaplib
gmail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
gmail.login('username@gmail.com', 'password')
...
```

---

[mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format usually means just that the messages are catenated after each other, with the caveat that each line that starts with `From` needs to be escaped with `>`, very easy to write out by hand from Python script, though also supported by standard library with [mailbox.mbox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html)

Comment: Does this library let me download them to a .mbox filetype?

Answer (score -1):

Standard [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) is working fine for me. Another standard library [mailbox](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html) could be useful as well.